# Why my css file is not loading when deployed in heroku? P.S: I'm using ejs

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ejs, web-deployment

I have deployed my app on heroku. Using Node.js + Express + ejs.

But for some reason it is not loading my css.

**Errors** :

1. `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`
2. `Refused to apply style from 'https://**.herokuapp.com/public/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`
3. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

These are the errors I'm getting. When I inspect the page.

**My file structure** :
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k42gy.png)

**app.js code**

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const date=require(__dirname +"/date.js");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

**header.ejs code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TO-DO LIST</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
</head>
```

Please someone help me with this issue.

---

**Edit :**

- The above mentioned errors (1 and 3) are not due to the code. They are due to the added extensions to my browser.
- After removing the extensions error 1 and error 3 were gone. But error 2 still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rigorous research and trying so many ways finally I'm able to resolve my issue by myself.

I have done some major changes, and my issue was resolved.

- I have changed my file structure a little bit.
- From [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k42gy.png) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knagm.png)
- I have created a new directory called partials in the views directory and moved my header.ejs and footer.ejs files to that directory.
- In header.ejs file I have changed the code from this
- ```html
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
  ```

  to

  ```html
  <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
  ```
- In other .ejs files I have included the header.ejs and footer.ejs as follows:

  ```html
  <%- include("partials/header"); -%>
  <%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
  ```

And that's how I am able to solve my issue.

***Hakuna Matata***